# How to Install Redis on a shared hosting account

Tags: linux, redis

I have a shared hosting account with HostGator and I have to install Redis on it. How can I do that as I do not have root access to the server? Is there any way to, I don't know, upload the extracted files on to the server and executing them?

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server? I mean with a simple user, no `root` required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. (this is a bit late but I hit this problem today and your question was the first hit on google).

I'm doing this on OS-X but it should be exactly the same on all platforms. The installer uses `make test` and some of the tests require privileged access. On the session that I watched it was some of the leak testing tools needing to access another process.

If you just run `make` then you will skip the tests completely. The binary that you need is left as `src/redis-server`. If you run it then it stays in user mode and uses a high port number (no privileges needed). This means that you can skip the actual installation step to `/bin`and `/etc` and run it in-place.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to be root to download and compile the code (well if you already have the dependencies).

try 
http://redis.io/download

Comment: How can the installation add files to directories like /etc and others without write permission on a shared hosting server? I was able to download and extract the .tar.gz file but couldn't run the installation properly as it gave me permission errors.

Comment: @BasitSaeed It can't, you may have to perform the installation procedure manually so Redis ends up in userspace.